# How do you provoke a floating point error in 32 bits

Tags: c, assembly, intel, interrupt, x86-16

How do you provoke a floating point error in 32 bits (commonly known as coprocessor error [INT 16 :8086].

Comment: What situation inspired you to ask that?  People like me normally expect non-floating point instructions to not have floating point effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Art of Assembly, FPU Control Register](http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH14/CH14-3.html#HEADING3-11)

> Bits zero through five are the exception masks. These are similar to the interrupt enable bit in the 80x86's flags register. If these bits contain a one, the corresponding condition is ignored by the 80x87 FPU. However, if any bit contains zero, and the corresponding condition occurs, then the FPU immediately generates an interrupt so the program can handle the degenerate condition.

Make sure the Control Register has 6 lsbs cleared, then produce any of the conditions. Divide by zero is probably the easiest to produce.

```
int main()
{
    int cw=0;
    asm("fstcw (%0)\n\t"::"r"(&cw):"memory"); cw &= ~0x3f;
    asm("fldcw (%0)\n\t"::"r"(&cw):"memory");
    asm("fldz");  // divide 1 by 0.0 
    asm("fld1");  // or just omit these two loads if you have 387+ :)
    asm("fdivp");
    asm("wait");  // This is mandatory
    return 0;
}
```

Output on x64/i5 / gcc 4.6 / ubuntu

> Floating point exception

Comment: Disclaimer -- I don't understand the part "in 32 bits". On 386+ though there's additional exception for stack over/underflow. An underflow should be doable by calling e.g. fdivp when presumably there are no values in the fp-stack.

Comment: Aki, In your comment, did you mean 486+?  Or coprocessors?

Comment: I meant 80387 coprocessor. It's predecessors didn't have Overflow exceptions. But still I don't get the requirement for 32-bit.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  Well I guess that the requirement for 32bit makes the  task unsolvable, by possibly asking for a solution involving non-FP instructions only.